# SQL Query to Select by String ID

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have the below line of code in an ASP.Net Page

```
var strSelect = String.Format("select EMailAddress from dbo.Master where StringID='", values["StringID"], "'");
```

This results in an error

> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''.
>   Incorrect syntax near ''.

What's wrong with the syntax?

> Source Error:

```
 Line 65:                   cmd.Connection.Close();
 Line 66:               if (!MVCFunctions.HandleError())
 Line 67:                   throw e;
 Line 68:               return null;
 Line 69:             }
```

Comment: is it the proper usage of `string.Format` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not using `String.Format` correctly:

```
var strSelect = String.Format("select EMailAddress from dbo.Master where StringID='", 
                  values["StringID"], "'");
```

should be

```
var strSelect = 
     String.Format("select EMailAddress from dbo.Master where StringID='{0}'", 
                  values["StringID"]);
```

Additional information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx

With that said, please look into using parameterized queries as this can be vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: Thank you very much that did the trick I will research on that :)